# Android Mapping Remote Control Keys with Virtual Key Board and append the text in edittext

Tags: android, keymapping, remote-control

I am working on a project based on Mapping the Remote control keys with android device.Here I can able to get the keycodes of Remote keys and return values for it based on the key codes.But the problem is, I don't know how to append the values inside the edit text.If I pressed the remote keys, it always returns numbers only.Guide me in a right way to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Sample Code:

I am having the below code in a Global Activity.And I extended all other Activities from this one.

```
public String switchedMethod(int key)
{
    String letter = null;
    switch(key)
    {
      case 9:
          letter = "a";
          break;
      case 10:
          letter = "b";
          break;
      case 11:
          letter = "c";
          break;
      case 12:
          letter = "d";
          break;
      case 13:
          letter = "e";
          break;
      case 14:
          letter = "f";
          break;
      case 15:
          letter = "g";
          break;
      case 16:
          letter = "h";
          break;
    }
    Log.v("LETTER", ""+letter);
    return letter;
}
   @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    Log.v("KEYCODE", ""+keyCode);
    switchedMethod(keyCode);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


       //Code Related to Edit Text
public class SettingsSubElementCreator extends GlobalActivity
{
       protected void handleSDEditText(int optionItemsCurrentItemIndex) 
{
    LinearLayout subLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    subLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    subLayout.removeAllViews();
    createButtons();

    // I NEED TO APPEND THE TEXT FOR THE BELOW EDITTEXT VIEW

    final EditText SDEditText = new EditText(this);
    SDEditText.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

    subLayout.addView(SDEditText);
    subLayout.addView(okcancelButtonLayout);

    final ModifySettingsDialog dialog = new ModifySettingsDialog(this,
            R.string.video_aspect_adjustment_sd,
            optionItemsCurrentItemIndex, subLayout, false);
    dialog.show();

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"inside video aspect adjustment sd"+ SDEditText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: @Abdullah Shoaib - Any idea about this issue.Please share it

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried related to EditText too.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib - That's what I don't how to append the values with the edit text.I'hv created a dynamic view for edit text in a dialog.